# FTP Plain Text File To Specific Directory

Tags: vb.net, ftpwebrequest

I am taking over a process that is completely done by hand and trying to automate it.  One step is to FTP a plain text file to a specific directory on an FTP server.  Everything I see when I search is dropping the file on the server not putting it in a specific directory.  The error I get is file name not allowed, except it is the same name that is manually FTP'ed.  Below is what code I have.  What am I missing?

```
    LocalFile = Path.GetFileName(TheFile)

    URI = TheHost & RemoteDir & LocalFile

    TheFtpClient = CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)

    TheFtpClient.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(UserName, PassWord)
    TheFtpClient.KeepAlive = False

    TheFtpClient.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

    FileReader = New StreamReader(TheFile)
    FileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(FileReader.ReadToEnd())
    FileReader.Close()
    TheFtpClient.ContentLength = FileContents.Length

    RequestStream = TheFtpClient.GetRequestStream()
    RequestStream.Write(FileContents, 0, FileContents.Length)
    RequestStream.Close()

    TheResponse = CType(TheFtpClient.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

    Console.WriteLine("[" & TheResponse.StatusDescription & "]")
```